# CSS drop down menu shifts sub menu items to the right but only in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I am using some code that I found for a drop down menu.  It works perfect in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.  In IE, the sub menu items are shifted over to the right instead of appearing directly below the main menu items. (Using my code as an example, the "Level 2.1," "Level 2.2," etc are not directly under "Two Levels" when I hover.  They are shifted right.

I have been trying to fix this for 2 days.  I'm not great with the coding so even though I have done lots of researh for a solution, I do not understand and can't quite get it right.  I'm hoping someone can help me or else I'm just going to give up.

I'd like to leave the doctype and meta tag as is.

**My doctype is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

**And I have meta tag:**

```
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```

**And here is the CSS:**

```
#nav {
 float: left;
 font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid #121314;
 border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 background: #3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

#nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

#nav ul li {
 float: left;
}

#nav ul li a {
 float: left;
 color: #d4d4d4;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
/* Drop Down Menu By helperblogger.com */
#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover > a {
 color: #252525;
 background: #3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 -1px #000;
}

#nav li ul a:hover,
#nav ul li li:hover > a {
 color: #2c2c2c;
 background: #5C9ACD;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.17, rgb(61,111,177)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(80,136,199)), color-stop(1, rgb(92,154,205)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 border-top: 1px solid #7BAED9;
 text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
/* Drop Down Menu By helperblogger.com */
#nav li ul {
 background: #3C4042;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 left: -999em;
 margin: 35px 0 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 160px;
 z-index: 9999;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#nav li:hover ul {
 left: auto;
}

#nav li ul a {
 background: none;
 border: 0 none;
 margin-right: 0;
 width: 120px;
 box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
 border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.nav ul li ul li {
    display: list-item;
    float: none;
}

.nav ul li ul li ul {
    top: 0;
}

.nav ul li ul li a {
    font: normal 13px Verdana;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#nav li li ul {
 margin: -1px 0 0 160px;
 visibility: hidden;
}

#nav li li:hover ul {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

**And here is the html:**

```
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">One Dropdown</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two Levels</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Level 2.1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Level 2.2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Level 2.3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Level 2.4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Level 2.5</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: next time post your code in jsfiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/faywk/

Comment: Sorry, I will try to do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after spending 5 days straight on this, not getting it to work, and hours of research, I finally found a great tutorial that explains how to create a css drop down menu and it works correctly for all browsers, including IE 7,8, and 9.  So I used that code and modified it to suit my preferences.

Thank you @Prasad and @Xiaoyi for your help.

In case this may be helpful to others (probably only beginners like me) here is the link.  There was one small fix to include a z-index so make sure you read through all the comments if your menu drop downs are covered by other elements.  I would never ever want anyone to go through what I went through.  http://designmodo.com/css3-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 0):

make following changes in your css

```
#nav {
 float: left;
 font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid #121314;
 border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 background: #3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
*height:34px; //IE7 Hack
}

#nav li ul {
 background: #3C4042;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 left: -999em;
 margin: 35px 0 0;
 position: absolute;
*position:relative;//DD menu will start after </a> IE7
 width: 160px;
 z-index: 9999;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Prasad!!  However, this did not work.  The menu was all over the place. Not sure what's going on.  My goal is to get the menu to be the same across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

simple fix:

```
#nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
  left: 0;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/faywk/2/

Comment: Thank you xiaoyi for helping!  However this did not work either.  Almost but not quite.  In Firefox and Chrome, the main menu is ok but the sub menu items are all the way over on the left side of the page.  In IE, the main menu is not right. It is in a diagonal and the sub menu items are all the way over on the left side of the page.  I see that your code works in jsfiddle so why would it not work in the browsers?

Comment: if it works on isfiddle it's the correct code. there must be some of your own code messed it up.

Comment: xiaoyi, I opened another question to include all of the code I have in the head tag.  Could you take a look and see if you see where the problem is?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634465/blogger-css-drop-down-menu-shifts-sub-menu-items-to-the-right-only-in-ie  Thank you!