# Blogger css drop down menu shifts sub menu items to the right only in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, blogger

I am trying to add a css drop down menu to my blog in blogger.

I am using some code that I found for a drop down menu. It works perfect in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE. I am using IE9 but have a meta tag to emulate IE7.  In IE, the sub menu items are shifted over to the right instead of appearing directly below the main menu items. (Using my code as an example, the "2010 Interviews," "2011 Interviews," etc are not directly under "Radio Interviews" when I hover. They are shifted right.

I have been trying to fix this for 4 days. I'm not great with the coding so even though I have done lots of researh for a solution, I do not understand and can't get it right. I'm hoping someone can help me or else I'm just going to give up.

I'd like to leave the doctype and meta tag as is.

Here is the html (which I have added to an html/javascript gadget).

```
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="http://brunomarstester.blogspot.com/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Award Shows</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">AMAs</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">BET Awards</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Grammys</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">MTV VMAs</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Other Award Shows</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Hooligan Band</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Dwayne Dugger II</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Eric Hernandez</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Jamareo Artis</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">James King</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">John Fossitt</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Kameron Whalum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Phredley Brown</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Radio Interviews</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">2010 Interviews</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2011 Interviews</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2012 Interviews</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2013 Interviews</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">TV/Other Interviews</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">2010 Interviews</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2011 Interviews</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2012 Interviews</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2013 Interviews</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Performances</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Award Shows</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Concerts</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Night Clubs</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Radio Stations</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Special Events</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">TV</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Guest Star</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">International</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Philippines</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">UK</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the top portion & head of the code for the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
<head>
<!--BELOW ADDED BY CW-->
    <meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
<!--ABOVE ADDED BY CW-->

<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular,bold' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<b:skin><![CDATA[/*
-----------------------------------------------
Blogger Template Style
Name:        TheStyle      
Author :     http://www.soratemplates.com
Designer:    http://www.elegantthemes.com
Date:        Sep 2012
License:  This free Blogger template is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License, which permits both personal and commercial use. However, to satisfy the 'attribution' clause of the license, you are required to keep the footer links intact which provides due credit to its authors. For more specific details about the license, you may visit the URL below:
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0
----------------------------------------------- */
body#layout #tabbed-area,body#layout #search-form,#navbar,#credit,.date-header,.feed-links,.post-location,.post-share-buttons,.post-icons{display: none !important;}
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,ul,li,a,p,span,img,dd{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;text-decoration:none;border:none;outline:none;vertical-align:baseline;}
body#layout #PageList1{float:none}
body#layout #main-wrapper { float: left; width: 70%; }
body#layout #header-wrapper { margin-bottom:0 }
body {
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    color: #7A7575;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans',Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 19px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

a {color: #00B7F3;}
a:hover {}

#container {
    background: url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-RMDcXHbrWZg/UEsR-ChcvgI/AAAAAAAADjo/VAfyrAnPmWU/s474/container-bg.png) repeat-y scroll 0 0 #323232;
    position: relative;
}

#container2 {
    background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-9DPCUMBJJCA/UEsR-Di3HOI/AAAAAAAADjk/DJ6QpA0gozk/s372/container-bg-right.png) repeat-y scroll right top transparent;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 0 0 0 3%;
}

#header-wrapper {margin-bottom: 50px;}
#header{}
#header-inner {padding:50px 0 0}
#header,#header a { color: #fff }
#header a:hover {}
#header h1 {font-size:120px;text-transform:uppercase;padding:0}
#header img {max-height:105px}
#header .description {margin-bottom: 10px;padding-left: 10px;}

#PageList1{float: left;}
ul.nav { padding-top: 20px; }
.nav li {float: left;}
ul.nav a { font-size: 24px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding-bottom: 58px; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 8px 8px 12px;}
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav > li.current-menu-item > a,.PageList li.selected a { color: #dcc08e; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000; }

#search-form {float: right; background: url(https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-XddNEOGCeQk/UEsSBq5Y6GI/AAAAAAAADlU/ykXt8G9jU4M/s191/search-bg.png) no-repeat; width: 191px; height: 33px; margin: 12px 3% 0px 0px;}
input#searchinput { background:none; border: none; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic; color: #595959; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; margin-top:0px; padding-left:13px; width:146px; float: left; position: relative; top: 5px; }
input#searchsubmit { float:left; margin-top:10px; }

#content { padding-bottom: 25px; position: relative; }
#content .fullwidth {width: 100% !important;}
.entry { position: relative; margin: 0px 0px 24px; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #fff; box-shadow: 3px 6px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); }

p.postinfo {
    color: #2C2C2C;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    padding: 0 15px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
p { line-height:18px; }
div.category {line-height: 20px;text-align:right;background-color: #9a1d0d; display:block; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 2px; padding: 7px 8px 0 8px; max-height: 23px; overflow: hidden;}
div.category a {font-size: 22px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; }
span.month {font-size: 48px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 0px; padding-right: 8px;}  
span.date {display:block; position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 0px; padding-right: 8px;}

#content-bottom-bg {
    background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-xbMeEF1CMmQ/UEsSAIBn7CI/AAAAAAAADkg/uqKXOYFv49E/s4/footer-top.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4A4A4A;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 4px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

h3.post-title a { color: #00b7f3<!--#9A1D0D-->; font-size: 30px; text-transform: uppercase;overflow: hidden;<!--ADDED BY CW-->}
<!--BELOW ADDED BY CW-->
.post-outer {
     overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
<!--ABOVE ADDED BY CW-->

h1.post-title {
    color: #9A1D0D;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;<!--ADDED BY CW-->
    text-overflow: ellipsis;<!--ADDED BY CW-->
    white-space: nowrap;<!--ADDED BY CW-->

}
.entry h3 { padding: 0 15px; font-size: 24px;}
.thumbnail img{display:block;width:222px;height:180px;margin: 2px 0 14px 2px}
.entry.big .thumbnail img{width:466px;}
.thumbnail .overlay {background: url(https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-BW3EslWyQC0/UEsSArpUaaI/AAAAAAAADk4/2pQ8ayc3p4I/s222/overlay.png) no-repeat; display:block; position: absolute; height: 180px; width: 224px; top: 0px; left: 2px;}
.entry.big .overlay {background: url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-gA72kHflMgs/UEsSAv-CUOI/AAAAAAAADk8/h_PKHudGlOw/s466/overlay2.png) no-repeat; display:block; position: absolute; height: 180px; width: 480px; top: 0px; left: 2px;}
.entry-content {
    background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OUfcj2Qk9I4/UEsR-1Fsn-I/AAAAAAAADjw/4EEWnDRU4y0/s9/entry-bottom-bg.png) repeat-x scroll left bottom transparent;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.bottom-bg {
    background: url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-cAmQAE8B1IU/UEsR-_uxihI/AAAAAAAADkE/BhmnlPyrEOU/s6/entry-top-bg.png) repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom-bg .excerpt { height: 75px; padding: 10px 17px 0; }
.textright { text-align: right; }
.entry a.readmore { font-size: 28px; color: #a5a5a5; margin-top: -5px; display: block;}

p.post-meta, p.post-meta a {
    color: #2C2C2C;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.hr {
    background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-iGut9H4FeFU/UEsSARlKOUI/AAAAAAAADko/JKwCEvDZaSk/hr-bg.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.post blockquote { font: italic 13px georgia; margin: 1em 20px;}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    float: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 3% 0 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    width: 26%;
}

.sidebar {margin-top:15px}
.sidebar .widget,#tabbed .widget {background: #e7e7e7 url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OUfcj2Qk9I4/UEsR-1Fsn-I/AAAAAAAADjw/4EEWnDRU4y0/s9/entry-bottom-bg.png) repeat-x bottom left; padding-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; margin-bottom: 15px; box-shadow: 3px 6px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); }
.sidebar h2 {color:#9a1d0d; font-size:30px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase; background: url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-cAmQAE8B1IU/UEsR-_uxihI/AAAAAAAADkE/BhmnlPyrEOU/s6/entry-top-bg.png) repeat-x bottom left; padding: 21px 5px 9px 22px;}
.sidebar .widget-content {padding: 10px 5px 7px 22px;color:#7a7575;}            
.sidebar .widget-content ul { margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px; }
.sidebar .widget-content ul li { background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ca73xQGUkQ0/UEsSCt9xG0I/AAAAAAAADmA/IBvLBqoqbIo/s6/widget-bullet.png) no-repeat 0px 12px; padding:5px 0px 5px 13px; }
.sidebar .widget-content ul li ul { padding:3px 0px 0px 7px; margin: 0px 0px -7px; }            
.sidebar .widget-content a { color: #7a7575; text-decoration: none;}
.sidebar .widget-content a:hover { color: #595656; }

#tabbed-area { background: #d6d6d6 url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-cAmQAE8B1IU/UEsR-_uxihI/AAAAAAAADkE/BhmnlPyrEOU/s6/entry-top-bg.png) repeat-x bottom left; padding-bottom: 1px; }
#tabbed-area li { background:#d6d6d6; float: left; width: 33%; }
#tabbed-area li a { font-size: 30px; color: #9a1d0d; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ffffff; display: block; padding: 19px 8% 7px; background: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7v6_A-bd7Hk/UEsSCP2B4bI/AAAAAAAADlk/NntOh4bXlOw/tabbed-right-bg.png) repeat-y top right; text-transform: uppercase; }
#tabbed-area li.last a { background: none; }
#all_tabs a{color: #2b2b2b;}
#tabbed-area li a:hover,#all_tabs a:hover { text-decoration: none; color: #000000; }
#tabbed-area li.ui-state-active a { background-color: #e7e7e7; }
#tabbed .tab ul li { padding: 14px 7% 10px; background:#E7E7E7 url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-cAmQAE8B1IU/UEsR-_uxihI/AAAAAAAADkE/BhmnlPyrEOU/s6/entry-top-bg.png) repeat-x bottom left; }      
#tabbed img.smallthumb { float: left; border: 3px solid #d6d6d6; margin: 0 8px 5px 0px; }
#all_tabs span { color: #a1a1a1; display: block; font: italic 11px Georgia, serif; color: #a1a1a1; padding-top:4px; }
.ui-tabs-hide { display: none; }

#comments{overflow:hidden;margin-left:100px}
#comments h4{display:inline;padding:10px;line-height:40px}
#comments h4,.comments .comment-header,.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread .comment{position:relative}
#comments h4,.comments .user a,.comments .continue a{font-size:16px}
#comments h4,.comments .continue a{font-weight:normal;color:#fff}
#comments h4:after{content:"";position:absolute;bottom:-10px;left:10px;border-right:20px solid transparent;width:0;height:0;line-height:0}
#comments .avatar-image-container img{border:0}
.comment-thread{color:#111}
.comment-thread a{color:#777}
.comment-thread ol{margin:0 0 20px}
.comment-thread .comment-content a,.comments .user a,.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread .user a{color:#9A1D0D}
.comments .avatar-image-container,.comments .avatar-image-container img{width:48px;max-width:48px;height:48px;max-height:48px}
.comments .comment-block,.comments .comments-content .comment-replies,.comments .comment-replybox-single{margin-left:60px}
.comments .comment-block,.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread .comment{border:1px solid #ddd;background:#f9f9f9;padding:10px}
.comments .comments-content .comment{margin:15px 0 0;padding:0;width:100%;line-height:1em}
.comments .comments-content .icon.blog-author{position:absolute;top:-12px;right:-12px;margin:0;background-image: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-cz1ogKtwNBc/T-xs3x0de-I/AAAAAAAABwI/KlCgXlV7uo0/s36/author);width:36px;height:36px}
.comments .comments-content .inline-thread{padding:0 0 0 20px}
.comments .comments-content .comment-replies{margin-top:0}
.comments .comment-content{padding:5px 0;line-height:1.4em}
.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread{border-left:1px solid #ddd;background:transparent}
.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread .comment{width:auto}
.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread .comment:after{content:"";position:absolute;top:10px;left:-20px;border-top:1px solid #ddd;width:10px;height:0px}
.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread .comment .comment-block{border:0;background:transparent;padding:0}
.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread .comment-block{margin-left:48px}
.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread .user a{font-size:13px}
.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread .avatar-image-container,.comments .comment-thread.inline-thread .avatar-image-container img{width:36px;max-width:36px;height:36px;max-height:36px}
.comments .continue{border-top:0;width:100%}
.comments .continue a{padding:10px 0;text-align:center}
.comment .continue{display:none}
#comment-editor{width:103%!important}
.comment-form{width:100%;max-width:100%}

#blog-pager-newer-link {float: left;}
#blog-pager-older-link {float: right;}
#blog-pager { height: 73px; margin:0; padding:10px 0; clear:both; }
.pagenavi {position: relative;text-align: center;}
.pagenavi a { padding: 5px 7px !important; margin: 2px; text-decoration: none; border: none !important; color: #ffffff !important; background: none !important; font-weight: normal !important; font-size: 36px !important; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); }
.pagenavi span.current,.pagenavi span.extend,.pagenavi a:active,.pagenavi a:hover { padding: 5px 7px !important; margin: 2px; font-weight: normal !important; background: none !important; border: none !important; color:#dcc08e !important; font-size: 36px !important; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); }
.pagenavi .pages {display:none}
.pagenavi span#right-arrow {
    background: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-66Q_--yBc_M/UEsSBRccq0I/AAAAAAAADlM/zrJcbXcNkgk/s29/right-arrow.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3%;
    top: 1px;
    width: 27px;
}
.pagenavi span#left-arrow {
    background: url(https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-QeyupBWH9sU/UEsSAWpVU7I/AAAAAAAADkw/cwaKy9vzDTA/s29/left-arrow.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 29px;
    left: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    width: 27px;
}

#footer { background: #2c2c2c url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-9KpLVnuP-U8/UEsR_XHrdOI/AAAAAAAADkM/HCY21tY1qRw/s388/footer-leftbg.png) repeat-y; }
#footer-wrapper { background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jlWcqoo28UI/UEsR_kVd7pI/AAAAAAAADkU/E4TmyTCf7GI/s402/footer-rightbg.png) repeat-y top right; padding: 20px 7% 0px; }
#footer .column { width: 285px; margin: 0px 0px 45px; float: left; color: #d1d1d1; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; }
#footer .column h2 {color:#dcc08e; font-size: 30px; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 30px 0px 5px 0px; }
#footer .column ul li { margin-bottom: 11px; }
#footer .column ul a { color:#d1d1d1; text-decoration: none; background: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-z1-aXJmQ_6Q/UEsR_ZX8E8I/AAAAAAAADkc/Mdf9R5fj1qg/s42/footer-bullet.png) no-repeat 0 2px; padding-left:20px; }
#footer .column ul a:hover { background: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-z1-aXJmQ_6Q/UEsR_ZX8E8I/AAAAAAAADkc/Mdf9R5fj1qg/s42/footer-bullet.png) no-repeat bottom left; color:#fff; }
p#copyright { text-align: right; padding-bottom: 40px; color:#686868; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; font-size: 12px; }
p#copyright a { font-weight: bold; color:#8c8c8c; }

#random-tabbed img,#recent-tabbed img,#PopularPosts1 img {
    border: 3px solid #D6D6D6;
    float: left; 
    width:38px; 
    height:38px;
    margin: 0 8px 5px 0;
    padding:0
}
#PopularPosts1 li {}
.status-msg-body {position:relative !important}
.CSS_LIGHTBOX { z-index: 9999 !important; }
<!--BELOW ADDED BY CW-->
/* Drop Down Menu By helperblogger.com */
#nav {
 float: left;
 font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid #121314;
 border-top: 1px solid #2b2e30;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 background: #3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

#nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

#nav ul li {
 float: left;
}

#nav ul li a {
 float: left;
 color: #d4d4d4;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(59,63,65)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(72,76,77)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(75,77,77)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(59,63,65) 9%, rgb(72,76,77) 55%, rgb(75,77,77) 78% );
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
/* Drop Down Menu By helperblogger.com */
#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover > a {
 color: #252525;
 background: #3C4042;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 -1px #000;
}

#nav li ul a:hover,
#nav ul li li:hover > a {
 color: #2c2c2c;
 background: #5C9ACD;
 background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.17, rgb(61,111,177)), color-stop(0.51, rgb(80,136,199)), color-stop(1, rgb(92,154,205)) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
 background: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(61,111,177) 17%, rgb(80,136,199) 51%, rgb(92,154,205) 100% );
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 border-top: 1px solid #7BAED9;
 text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
/* Drop Down Menu By helperblogger.com */
#nav li ul {
 background: #3C4042;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(77,79,79)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(67,70,71)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(69,70,71)) );
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(77,79,79) 9%, rgb(67,70,71) 55%, rgb(69,70,71) 78% );
 left: -999em;
 margin: 35px 0 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 160px;
 z-index: 9999;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#nav li:hover ul {
 left: auto;
}

#nav li ul a {
 background: none;
 border: 0 none;
 margin-right: 0;
 width: 120px;
 box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
 border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.nav ul li ul li {
    display: list-item;
    float: none;
}

.nav ul li ul li ul {
    top: 0;
}

.nav ul li ul li a {
    font: normal 13px Verdana;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#nav li li ul {
 margin: -1px 0 0 160px;
 visibility: hidden;
}

#nav li li:hover ul {
 visibility: visible;
}
/* Drop Down Menu By helperblogger.com */

<!--ABOVE ADDED BY CW-->

]]></b:skin>
<style type='text/css'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
#sidebar-wrapper {display:none}
.entry-inner{position:relative} 
.small { width:226px; }
.big { width:470px; }
<b:else/>
#main-wrapper{margin-left:-3%;float: left;width: 71%;}
.entry { background: #ffffff url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OUfcj2Qk9I4/UEsR-1Fsn-I/AAAAAAAADjw/4EEWnDRU4y0/s9/entry-bottom-bg.png) repeat-x; border: 1px solid #ffffff; padding: 30px 0px 0px; box-shadow: 3px 6px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); margin-bottom: 15px; }
.entry-inner { background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OUfcj2Qk9I4/UEsR-1Fsn-I/AAAAAAAADjw/4EEWnDRU4y0/s9/entry-bottom-bg.png) repeat-x bottom left; padding: 0px 4% 30px; } 
.info-panel { float: left; margin-right: 3%; width: 29%; }
.post-text img { max-width:420px; }
.info-panel h3.infotitle {
    color: #2C2C2C;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding:0 0 9px;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.info-panel .tags ul li { float: left; }
.info-panel .tags ul li a { display: block; padding: 10px 10px 8px; margin: 0px 3px 3px 0px; background: #efefef; font-size: 11px; color: #6e6e6e; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ffffff; }
.info-panel .tags ul li a:hover { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
.related ul li { background: url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-4A2wStB_txo/UEsSAwwBQWI/AAAAAAAADlE/k9ROBQlzCWE/s5/post-bullet.png) no-repeat scroll 0 7px transparent; padding: 0 0 5px 11px; }
.related ul li a { color: #7A7575; }
.related ul li a:hover { color: #000000; }
.share-panel,.related{margin-top:30px}
.share-panel img {margin: 0 7px 5px 0;}
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
.post-text { float: right; width: 68%; }
</b:if>
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('8 9(s,n){g s.h(/<.*?>/i,\'\').j(/\\s+/).k(0,n-1).l(\' \')}8 b(a){m p=o.q(a),5=\'\',4=p.r(\'4\');t(4.u>=1){5=\'<4 6="\'+4[0].6+\'" />\'}v{5=\'<4 6="w://A.B.C/-D/E-F/G/H-I/J.K" />\'}p.c=\'<2 3="L"><a 7="\'+y+\'">\'+5+\'<d 3="M"></d></a></2>\'+\'<e 3="N-O"><a 7="\'+y+\'">\'+x+\'</a></e>\'+\'<p 3="P">Q R \'+z+\'</p>\'+\'<2 3="S-T"><2 3="U-V"><2 3="W"><p>\'+9(p.c,X)+\'...</p>\'+\'<2 3="Y"><a 3="b" 7="\'+y+\'">&#f;&#f;</a></2>\'+\'</2></2></2>\'}',61,61,'||div|class|img|imgtag|src|href|function|stripTags||readmore|innerHTML|span|h3|187|return|replace|ig|split|slice|join|var||document||getElementById|getElementsByTagName||if|length|else|https||||lh4|googleusercontent|com|G9M2DTCTUwM|Tlh|2pwtc5I|AAAAAAAABKM|kCJg|Kf3W2M|no_image_yet|jpg|thumbnail|overlay|post|title|postinfo|Posted|by|entry|content|bottom|bg|excerpt|40|textright'.split('|'),0,{}))
//]]></script>
</head>
```

If anyone can help I would appreciate it so much.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue : In ie8, it work nicely, in ie7, the drop down simply does not expand. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUzFS/)

Comment: Thanks Kraz!  I'm very new to this jsfiddle.  Is there a way to test ie8 etc. with the fiddle?  Because what I see in your fiddle is perfect.  Just as it looks on the page in firefox and Chrome.  But when I view the page in IE, the sub menu items are shifted right.

Comment: Open IE developper tools (shortcut : F12). You'll have options to emulate IE8/IE7/Quicks mode (think IE6). Works everywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much Kraz!  That helped a lot.  Seems like only IE7 is giving the problem.  Now to figure out how to tweak my code.

Comment: I didn't take the time to pinpoint the problem, but here's some clue : You have loads of element who are floating and they are never cleared. Then you also have absolute-positionned element, and their parent are not `position:relative`. Try to debug it from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dUzFS/2/) (and that left:-999px is surely part of the problem).

Comment: Kraz,  thanks for at least pointing me in a direction.  I was able to fiddle around with it and almost get it to work.  I came close but never quite right.  Instead I found a tutorial that helped me create a drop down menu that works in all browsers including IE (7,8,and9).

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of some help. And switching to another dropdown menu was a good idea, this one seemed to have way too much css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after spending 5 days straight on this, not getting it to work, and hours of research, I finally found a great tutorial that explains how to create a css drop down menu and it works correctly for all browsers, including IE 7,8, and 9. So I used that code and modified it to suit my preferences.

Thank you @Kraz for your help.

In case this may be helpful to others (probably only beginners like me) here is the link. There was one small fix to include a z-index so make sure you read through all the comments if your menu drop downs are covered by other elements. I would never ever want anyone to go through what I went through. http://designmodo.com/css3-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 0):

Cool tutorial i have found a website with good menu bars and other css designs you may like the designs.

http://freebietemplate.com/css-designs/css-designs.html

have a nice day